# How to play the default ringtone in flutter?

Tags: audio, dart, flutter, ringtone

I'm trying to play ringtones (and specifically a device's default one) with Flutter. It seems there isn't an flutter internal way to do it so I'm trying to use the [audioplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer) plugin, using this code:

```
AudioPlayer audioPlugin = new AudioPlayer();
audioPlugin.play('ringtone-uri');
```

The issue with this is:

- Is there a constant to invoke the default ringtone like in Android's native

```
   DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI ?
```

I would like to avoid using channels with native code as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is late already but this might help somebody in future.

There are some packages you can download from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) to get you the default ringtone of the phone, you can check this out [flutter ringtone player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player)

Comment: There is no support for iOS default ringtone uri

Comment: There is a lot of complication in changing iOS ringtones, Everyone is saying it is not possible to change ringtones in iOS, then how GarageBand is changing iOS ringtones programmatically.